# Oven/ Range problem

Tags: repair, oven

I recently replaced the light bulb in the oven. I pressed the oven light button while cooking nachos and hear a pop and the bulb went out, the heat went away, the display that shows the temp, time... went off. Breaker didn't trip, there's still power as the burners still work. Any ideas? New wiring in the oven? New fuse?